# Define the function $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{−1\}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 2x/(x+1) $.Prove that f is one-to-one but not onto.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am struggling mainly with figuring out how it is not an onto function. Please let me know, my professor didn't do any examples like this one.

$$2\frac{x1}{x1}+1 = 2\frac{x2}{x2}+1 $$

$$2x1(x1+1) = 2x2(x2+1)\\
x1 = x2 $$

one-to-one

$$2\frac xx+1 = -1\\
2x = -1(x+1)\\
2x = -x-1 \\
x = -1/3 \\
-\frac13 \ne-1 $$

Therefore function is not onto

Comment: You have added many irrelevant tags to your question. Also, where is your attempt? Edit your attempt in.

Comment: What is the definition of a map $f\colon X\to Y$ which is onto (=surjective)? That is the first step, known the definition.

Comment: For a hint, let $y=\frac{2x}{x+1}$. See what values $y$ can and can't take. Can every $y$ take the value of every real number?

Comment: Thanks for editing in your attempt. Why cannot $y$ be equal to $0$? If we put $x=0$ (which is in the function's domain), we get $y=0$.

Comment: What? I do not understand how you concluded the function is not onto by saying $-\frac{1}{3}$ is not equal to $-1$. A comment telling us about your thought process would help us help you.

Comment: i am not sure tbh how to determine if it isnt or is

Comment: Alright, a function is said to be onto if every element in the codomain (in this case, the codomain is the set of all reals) has an image. Are you comfortable with this definition, as in do you understand it?

Comment: Alternative approach... show $f$ has an inverse by finding it. The domain of the inverse is the range of the function.

Comment: @DavidP but a non-onto function has no inverse, right?

Comment: @heisenbruh Every one-to-one function has an inverse with a potentially restricted domain

Comment: Yes, and in the process of restricting that domain, OP would've found the value that's causing the problem, hence removing the need to find the inverse.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

To show that the function is one-to-one, let $x_1, \, x_2 \in \mathbb R\backslash\{-1\}$, such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, i.e.
$$
\frac{2x_1}{x_1 + 1} = \frac{2x_2}{x_2 + 1} \; .
$$
Now multiply the equation with the denominators of the fractions:
$$
2x_1(x_2+1) = 2x_2(x_1+1) \; .
$$
Expand and conclude that $x_1 = x_2$. This shows that the function is one-to-one.

To show that the function is not onto, you might first want to sketch the function. Then you can probably guess, that the function will never reach the value 2. To prove this, assume that there is a $x \in \mathbb R \backslash \{-1\}$, such that $f(x) = 2$. This means that
$$
\frac{2x}{x+1} = 2 \; .
$$
Now go on and conclude a contradiction from that.

Comment: Ahh I see, so sketching the function helps the most, so by solving for x I get 2x = 2x +2 and the after cancelling out the 2x i get 2 = 0 which is not true